# How to return a specific page for any web requests that don't point to any file in IIS web.config?

Tags: iis, web-config

In asp.net 4.5.2 (web api), I want to have it so that, for any web request (that's not an api), if it does not point to any file (i.e. would result in 404), it should just return the root page ("/"), but without changing the link, the link should still be what I typed.

How can I set this in the web.config?

Comment: Check out http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-catch-all-route-parameter-binding.  Also, the 404 you are seeing is an ASP.NET 404 and not the IIS 404.  Your post would be much better with ASP.NET tags on it

Answer (score 0):

You could use below rule, it will rewrite page if file or directory does not exist. it will just rewrite page url will be same.

```
<rule name="Rewrite to index" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.sample1.com/index.html" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
```

[image]

Regards,
Jalpa.

Comment: This is not a valid solution as the WebAPI calls that he does want for WebAPI will also not match to a directory or file.